# Knowledge in Site.com

Tags: knowledge, site.com

I want to expose Knowledge using the site.com publisher, but I am running into some query limitations. I have written SOQL queries for knowledge in the past so I under stand that there is some implementation restrictions, but I was wondering if anyone has gotten knowledge to work in site.com without using a Self-Service template using the Data Page Elements: 
[image]

Comment: Are you using Communities or standalone Site.com?

Comment: I am using communities. In my case I chose the Koa template, then deleted the stock pages that came with it (Home and Login) and created a new blank page not associated with the template. By doing this you gain access to the Data page elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error clearly points out you will need to flter your query via publication status .

In your Connection parameters add a status field filter with check

```
PublishStatus='Online'
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but it seems like the PublishStatus field is not available in the query builder.

Comment: Check FLS for guest profile .Because of FLS the field my not be available

Comment: The issue was that I was missing Language = 'en_US' AND PublishStatus = 'Online' in the SOQL query. Found this by using Workbench. Thanks for all your help Mohith, you definitely pointed me in the right direction!